# How to Access to Already Uploaded Docx Files in Django to search needed words?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to edit the needed uploaded file on webpage by searching and replacing the wanted words. How can I get the text of that doc file?

I have a filefield in my models and I get the doc files in a list on my webpage,where I am able to delete the needed file or upload a new one. I try to edit the wanted uploaded doc file by creating a function in my views.py. I have tried to use docx module to open the uploaded file, and also have tried io.StringIO() but I did not manage to get the desired output.

## models.py

```
class DocFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    agreement = models.FileField(upload_to='')
```

## views.py

```
def edit_file(request, upload_id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(DocFile, id=upload_id)
    content = instance.agreement.open(mode='rb')
    variables = []
    for line in content:
        match = re.findall(r"\{(.*?)\}", line.text)
        variables.append(match)
        return render(request, 'uploads/file_detail.html', {
            'variables': variables
        })
```

or

```
def edit_file(request, upload_id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(DocFile, id=upload_id)
    content = instance.agreement(upload_id)
    with open(content, 'rb') as f:
        instance.agreement = File(f)
        source = io.StringIO(f)
        document = Document(source)
        variables = []
        for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
            match = re.findall(r"\{(.*?)\}", paragraph.text)
            variables.append(match)
        for table in document.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                for cell in row.cells:
                    match = re.findall(r"\{(.*?)\}", cell.text)
                    variables.append(match)
        source.close()
        target = io.StringIO()
        document.save(target)
    return render(request, 'uploads/file_detail.html', {
        'variables': variables
    })
```

## file_detail.html

```
{% block content %}

    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if variables %}
        {% for variable in variables %}
            {% for var in variable %}
                {{ var }} <br /><input type="text", name="statement">
                <br />
                <br />
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Download">
    {% endif %}
    </form>

    <a href="{{ template.agreement }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    Edit
    </a>

{% endblock %}
```

When I run the first view function I get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /template/11/

'bytes' object has no attribute 'text'
```

And when I run the second view function method I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /template/11/

'FieldFile' object is not callable
```